# Words that link to other words puzzles

Tags: word

Complete a five letter word that will join the two given words

e.g. MAIL   _ _ _ _ _   FORM, will be ORDER

FIRE    _ _ _ _ _   CLOCK, will be ALARM

When solved, it will spell a topical word in the 2nd column

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

RISE _____ BOARD

> A**B**OVE

CARE _____ GROWN

> F**U**LLY

NO _____ FORM

> E**N**TRY

SPRING _____ RING

> O**N**ION

MOTOR _____ LANE

> C**Y**CLE

Final Answer:

> **BUNNY**
> (Happy Easter!)